# problems accessing current_user in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, observer-pattern

There are a lot of questions regarding this problem, "how to access current_user in model", i tried some and ended up doing the "old way", setting

```
 cattr_accessor :current_user
```

in my *FeedObserver*, and set

```
FeedObserver.current_user = current_user
```

in my *ApplicationController* with an before_filter.

Unfortunately it seems that it does not work as expected, and sometimes a different user is used in the FeedObserver.

I'm using rails 3.2.2, ruby 1.9.3p0, nginx, unicorn. i can't really explain this behavior, because
the before_filter should set the current_user for each request, and should not be overwritten with an different user... ?

```
class FeedObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  cattr_accessor :current_user
  observe :account, :user

  def after_create(ressource)
    log!(ressource)
  end

  def log!(ressource, event_name)
    feed_item = FeedItem.new(
      user: current_user,
      data: ressource.changes,
      account_id: current_user.account.id
    )
    feed_item.save if feed_item.valid?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [sentient_user](https://github.com/bokmann/sentient_user) gem for your purpose

Comment: yeah, i checked the code and it uses the "Thread method". which is great, but i need to know why my code is not working, maybe the same issue could happen with this method. (also i need to set more then just the current_user)

Answer (score 0):

not sure what caused the error, i guess it was just the concurrent request which overwrote the variables. as @Andrei suggested i tried the sentient_user gem. but the sentient_user has the same problem which can be resolved with:

```
  module SentientController
    def self.included(base)
      base.class_eval {
        around_filter do |controller, action|
          User.current = controller.send(:current_user)
          begin
            action.call
          ensure
            User.current = nil
          end      
        end
      }
    end
  end
```

that fixes the thread leaking problem...